# Inserting row of text before and after when a column's text changes in a Pandas Dataframe, in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, row

Python beginner here. I have a Pandas Dataframe where I would like to insert a row with text in the first column based off values from another column. My example of data is below:

**Current Dataframe**:

| value | type | section |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | brown | sect1 |
| 1 | green | sect1 |
| 0 | blue | sect2 |
| 0 | brown | sect3 |
| 0 | black | sect4 |
| 1 | yellow | sect4 |
| 2 | green | sect4 |
| 0 | blue | sect5 |

**Desired updated Dataframe:**

| value | type | section |
| --- | --- | --- |
| START | brown | sect1 |
| 1 | green | sect1 |
| END |  |  |
| START | blue | sect2 |
| END |  |  |
| START | brown | sect3 |
| END |  |  |
| START | black | sect4 |
| END |  |  |
| START | black | sect4 |
| 1 | yellow | sect4 |
| 2 | green | sect4 |
| END |  |  |
| START | blue | sect5 |
| END |  |  |

Notice I would like to remove the beginning values of '0' and replace with 'START'. The 'START' and 'END' rows need to occur when the sect value changes to a new value.

I have my current Dataframe set up as seen above, but I truly am not sure how to correctly update the Dataframe to do this. Any suggestions on how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using boolean indexing and [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
# identify changes of section
m = df['section'].ne(df['section'].shift(-1))

# repeat last row per group
idx = df.index.repeat(m.add(1))
out = df.loc[idx]

# clear END
# assign END to last value
# assign START to first value
m2 = idx.to_series().duplicated()
out[m2] = ''
out.loc[m2, 'value'] = 'END'
out.loc[m2.shift(fill_value=True), 'value'] = 'START'
```

Output:

```
   value    type section
0  START   brown   sect1
1      1   green   sect1
1    END                
2  START    blue   sect2
2    END                
3  START   brown   sect3
3    END                
4  START   black   sect4
5      1  yellow   sect4
6      2   green   sect4
6    END                
7  START    blue   sect5
7    END
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any change in my output. Does the variable 'm2' in your above code need to just be changed to 'm' like you have it in the `m = df['section'].ne(df['section'].shift(-1))`

Comment: No `m2` is a different mask. Can you provide a reproducible input as DataFrame constructor?

Comment: My Dataframe is larger than the one I gave you as example with more columns and rows of data. Does this influence the code above that you wrote?

Comment: does the `fill_value` in the `out.loc[m2.shift(fill_value=True)` line need to be fill_ and whatevery the column name is?

Comment: @ConnorGarrett No. [`fill_value`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) is the name of the parameter. This example doesn't modify `df` - `out` should contain the output you're looking for. Is this not the case?

Comment: @jqurious this doesn't make any changes unfortunately to my output dataframe. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @ConnorGarrett It creates a dataframe called `out` with the changes. Are you checking that? https://bpa.st/raw/TNBPG

Comment: @jqurious wow, yup you're right. I was still checking my old datfaframe name. Thanks so much!